# Dependencies setting folder in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core

**I am working with ASP.NET Core MVC (RTM Preview 2 version).**

**I've insertred file bower.json into my project and configured dependency settings for bootstrap as follows.**

```
{
  "name": "AspNetBlog",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7"
  }
}
```

For some reason there is no folder "Dependencies" in my project.

Thus bootstrap dependency is not inserted into it.

**Can you tell me what is the reason of such behaviour of my project?**
Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install packages using [bower install](https://bower.io/#install-packages) command:

```
# installs the project dependencies listed in bower.json
$ bower install
```